# How to sed all points except decimal ones

Tags: bash, exception, sed, replace, numbers

I'm trying to remove all points in a file except the one used for decimals

Example :
`Hello everyone. How. to sed 4.32 and 4. ?`

Should be replaced by :
`Hello everyone How to sed 4.32 and 4. ?`

I tried this : `sed 's/[^0-9]\.[^0-9]//g'` but it's not working properly

Result : `Hello everyonHoto sed 4.32 and 4. ?`

and this `sed '/[0-9].[0-9]/ ! s/\.//g'` but it doesn't work either. Its not removing any '.' : `Hello everyone. How. to sed 4.32 and 4. ?`

Comment: you are selecting the non digits as well and replacing them. You could use a capture group `()` and put them back.

Comment: You should include an IP address in your sample input/output to make it interesting - "My IP address is 10.10.10.10 today".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
sed -E 's/([^0-9])\.([^0-9])/\1\2/g'
```

which matches any non digit char, followed by a literal `.` and a non digit char, and replaces it with the two non digit characters.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

`sed -E ':a; s/([^0-9]|^)\.([^0-9]|$)/\1\2/; ta;'`

## Test

```
echo '.Hello everyone. How... to sed 4.32 and 4. .' | 
  sed -E ':a; s/([^0-9]|^)\.([^0-9]|$)/\1\2/; ta;'
```

result

`Hello everyone How to sed 4.32 and 4.`

## Explanation

- We capture (`()`) the characters before and after the `.`, and re-add them (`\1\2`). (Enough to pass all tests. Thanks @Paolo)

However the headline requirement (`remove all points in a file except the one used for decimals`) suggest more. So I remove leading, trailing, and repeated `.` (ask your customer if this is what they want).

- We also (`|`) capture the start(`^`) and end(`$`) of the record.
- We repeat (`ta` conditional branch to `:a`, if we changed anything) ( Thanks to @diniramdhni for this one)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/([ [:alpha:]]|^)\./\1/;ta' input_file
Hello everyone How to sed 4.32 and 4. ?
```

Comment: I think that might also remove decimals without the leading zero, such as `.4`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with a single sed command, which replaces any sequence of dots not bounded by a number on at least one side:

```
s/\([^.[:digit:]]\|^\)\.\+\([^.[:digit:]]\|$\)/\1\2/
```

We use the `[:digit:]` character class to match all the locale's digit characters, and the replacement omits the sequence of dots we matched between the two capture groups.

It's easier to write if we pass the `-E` flag to sed, so that it uses extended regex syntax, using fewer `\` escapes.

#### Demo:

```bash
echo '.Hello everyone. How... to replace a.b .3 4.32 and 4. .' |
    sed -E -e 's/([^.[:digit:]]|^)\.+([^.[:digit:]]|$)/\1\2/g'
```

```
Hello everyone How to replace ab .3 4.32 and 4.
```